# Refreshed MacBook + BootCamp unable to boot restored Windows 7 partition

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, error

I recently had my MacBook's HDD crap out on me. The OS X partition, in particular, quit working, but my Windows 7 partition was still in decent enough shape for me to grab an image. I got a replacement drive from Western Digital and restored the Win7 partition. I am able to see it from Mac OS X and am able to select it as a boot target with the Boot Disk tool, but when I reboot the machine, I get a gray screen for a few seconds and then a fully black one with simple white text reading "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and hit any key..."

Any ideas on what I need to do to get my Windows partition back up and running? I don't want to try a reinstall from the Win7 DVD (which I believe I've misplaced anyways) and Boot Camp Assistant doesn't offer any other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem establishing where the bootable partition begins.  Insert the Win7 dvd, boot up from it, and do a "startup disk repair" - which should not touch apps or data on the partition, but should restore the umm, boot-ability of said partition.

Comment: This sort-of worked. I am able to boot off the Win7 DVD; however, my Win7 install is not showing up in the list of repairable OS's on the box. Any idea what driver[s] I might need on a 2009 MacBook (white plastic) to get this working?

Comment: If you do need drivers (I don't think you should...) they would be on the OS X install disk, with the Bootcamp drivers.  I *think* Win7 allows you to insert the disk and it searches the disk for the correct drivers?  Try that.  But, I suspect, there is just some level of corruption here and not everything that needs to be in place is in place.  Meaning... back up your data, re-install Win7 on a fresh partition, and start from scratch.  Then restore your data.

Comment: Also - I know that's not what you wanted to do, but I think you might be out of options.  You are allowed to obtain Windows 7 however you please, if you own a license to it.  I would just download it and use your own, legally purchased key.  I wouldn't be surprised if you could actually download it direct from Microsoft, come to think of it...